# Wordpress, Template

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-plugin

Hola tengo una duda respecto a wordpress la cual es que mi equipo de trabajo compro una plantilla para trabajar en ella lo que pasa es que ocupo integrar un login, alguien sabe como integrar ese login a la plantilla que esta usando?

Comment: Saludos Germn, bienvenido a SOes, te sugiero leer https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4433/822 y por curiosidad, ¿has leído la documentación de Wordpress?

Comment: si péro al momento de agregar la pagina se fusiona junto con el contenido de la plantilla y lo que quiero que se visualice es el puro login

Comment: En ese caso, lee el contenido del enlace mostrado, esperamos la edición de tu pregunta para que la comunidada pueda ofrecerte una buena respuesta :D